# How to "address" a Python dataclass instance?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a Python dataclass defined as follow:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Accident:
    name: str
    year: int
    month: int
    num_accidents: int
```

I am creating an list of 'Accident' instances as follows:

```
accidents_list = []

# For the year 2020, create instances to record accidents per month
for month in range(1,13):
     # name will be in the format 2020-1, or 2020-2 and so on
     name = "2020" + "-" + str(month)
     # I am adding name, year and month, accidents to be added later
     accidents_list.append(Accident(name, 2020, month))
```

I would like to add the num of accidents to say 2020-02, which is Feb.
How do I reference the instance to add the num of accidents? I cannot add accidents in the for loop, since I don't have the data at the time of creation of this instance.

I want to do something like `2020-02.num_accidents = 5`. I do not want to iterate over the accidents_list, with an if statement for each month, that would be too much to do in case the list is really large.

```
for accidents in accidents_list:
    if (accident.name == '2020-02'):
        accident.num_accidents = 5
    elif (accident.name = '2020-03'):
        accident.num_accidents = 12
```

Comment: The same way you reference any other "kind of" instance? If you want to select instances by a key, *create a datastructure to select instance by a key* – say, a ``dict``.

Comment: Is there any reason why you create the ``Accident`` instances before you actually have the accident data? Why not create them later on when you do have the data?

Comment: > Is there any reason why you create the Accident instances before you actually have the accident data?

The number of accidents comes from API calls which are expensive, I am trying to optimize my code and have my data-structure "ready" and "pre-loaded", with the API calls filling in the number of accidents at a later time.

Comment: > Are you going to turn into the hulk when we tell you you are doing it all wrong? 

Lol, no, I am here to learn, no harm in telling me I am doing it the "wrong" way.

Comment: Ok, so where does the data like `5` and `12` come from?

Comment: Also, isn't "name" in the Accident class supposed to be a "key"? I thought that was one advantage of a dataclass, you can address it using the name.

Comment: It seems your ``Accident`` instances are at best worthless without the ``num_accidents``, at worst mislead. There doesn't seem to be any benefit to pre-creating the instances: creating instances is somewhat costly but still relatively cheap – *at best* your infrastructure to safely update existing instances will cost you as much as you safe via premature instantiation.

Comment: In this example the accident numbers, such as 5 and 12 are made up, but down the road in my code I will make some API calls to get them from a "accident" service.

Comment: Also, I will use these instances to make a time series graph down the road.

Comment: So, surely you will supply a *month*, say `'2020-02'` to that api which will then return `5`?

Comment: Yes, I will supply a year-month to the API and it will return the number of accidents in that month.

Comment: Ok, so I get it, it's best to add the num of accidents at the time of creation of these instances. I will work on that. But that still begs the questions, how do you reference instances? Is dict the recommended way? Can you point me to some code that gives an example so I can learn? Thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and did not pre-load my instance, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, you do need to iterate over the list to populate all the `Accident` instances with `num_accidents`:

```py
for accident in accidents_list:
    year_month = f'{accident.year}-{accident.month}'
    value = api.get_accidents_from_month(year_month)
    if value:
        accident.num_accidents = value
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems much cleaner than what I had.